# Create permission to a shared drive created by Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to do a process with PHP and Javascript to do the next:

Create a shared drive in my Drive.
Add a user to the created shared drive.

But at moment to create the drive, I am getting the Id of it, and at the moment to do the process to add the permission, I am getting error "The file not found".

This is my code:

```
return gapi.client.drive.drives.list({})
            .then(function(response) {
                var drives = response.result.drives;

                for (let index = 0; index < drives.length; index++) {
                    console.log(drives[index].id);
                    return gapi.client.drive.permissions.create({
                    "fileId": drives[index].id,
                    "transferOwnership": true,
                    "resource": {
                        "role": "owner",
                        "type": "user",
                        "emailAddress": "mail@gmail.com"
                    }
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log("Response", response);
                    },
                    function(err) {
                        console.error("Execute error", err);
                    });

                }
            },
            function(err) {
                console.error("Execute error", err);
            });
```

Help me!
Thanks for your comments !

Answer (score 0):

### Two things you need to know for creating permissions for shared drives

1. If you want to [create a permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) for a shared drive, you need to set the option `"supportsTeamDrives": true`. If you don't - that's what gives you the error `The file not found`
2. `"role": "owner"` and `"transferOwnership": true` are not valid options for a shared drive. They can only be used for files. Thus, you request would result in the error `Owner role is invalid for shared drive items`.